# 1-1 correspondence

Tags: grammar, nouns, agreement

This case really bothers me while I am speaking. Here is the situation: I have a group of four students. Each has the textbook named "Gandhi Readers". So, there are four textbooks, yet there is only one kind (Gandhi Readers). Now, when I wanna tell them to close the textbooks and put them in their bags, may I say "close your TEXTBOOK and put it in your BAG, please" for the reason of 1-1 correspondence?

Comment: The number of those nouns doesn't depend on the correspondence, but on the actual object that you want to name. If you are talking to a group of people who each has a book, then they possess a plurality of books. It should be *Close your books* They also possess a plurality of bags. It should be *Close your books and put them in your bags*. This is if you are talking to them as a group. The sentence that you used is talking about one book and one bag. If you want to apply it to each one of the group then you must quantify it properly: *Each of you, close your book and put it in your bag*.

Comment: @user337391 You should post this as an answer - it provides a concise explanation. Though the question is perhaps better suited to ELL.

Comment: PS Fadli, it's best not to use "wanna" instead of "want to" in formal writing unless it's in direct speech, and even then it should be used cautiously.

Comment: @user337391 There's also precedent to address instructions in the singular to a group, where "each" is implied.

Comment: It needs to be made clear that this is not a matter of logic but a matter of the rules of English. People often manage to convince themselves that there is logic behind their choice, when people using another language manage to convince themselves that their version is the one supported by the logic.  

In this particular case, *books* is correct in English but *livre* (i.e. *book*) is correct in French.

Comment: @user337391 That's not an adequate answer to the case at hand because the example sentence doesn't clearly communicate how many books should be closed. "Your book" can mean your personal book, while "your books" can either mean more than one of your personal books *or* at least one book (directed at "all of you", thereby multiple books). But in general you are correct. Plurality is a property of the object(s) the noun describes, not of the target audience.

Comment: @user337391 What if this is the situation. I am distributing one certificate to each student. The certificates are of the same kind. Should I say, "after you get your certificates, go home"?

Comment: @FadliSheikh Yes. That is correct. If you use *certificate* it sounds like you are talking to only one of them. You see, language often presents lots of ambiguities. When your goal is to be sure that your understood, then you would like to choose the construction with the least likely ambiguity. If you use the plural it might sound like each should take many certificates. If you use the singular that you are talking to only one person. Which one is more likely to be assumed by them if each one has only one certificate in their hands?

Comment: There are more elements that participate in communication than just the spoken words. Your position with respect to those people. Are they already holding the certificates, or are the papers on a table for them to pick up? Maybe if they still need to pick up the certificates calling them in plural makes it more likely the interpretation that they could pick up many of them. Did you look at one of them right in the eye when you said *After you get your certificate, go home.*?

Comment: If the main goal is not to convey a precise meaning then there is even more freedom. Suppose you are writing comedy. You are writing the script for Naked Gun 34 1/4. There is a cop who shouts to a group of armed robbers *Drop your weapon!*. Then confusion ensues. One of the robbers says *Who? Me?*. Another says *No, he is looking at me. Do you want me to drop my weapon? Why me?* etc. Then the policeman shouts angry *No! Drop your weapons!*. Then the second robber says *But I only have this revolver.*

Comment: Then a second policeman, who is armed to the teeth, enters the scene and says *He must be talking to me.*

Comment: Hahaha. You are really impressive, folks. Thanks a lot for the joke! It has really loosened my strained nerves. Thanks a lot for the answers as well. Now, it is crystal clear :)

Answer (score -1):

yes, at least that is what every other teacher does. if you say close your textbooks, well, students (those that actually pay attention at least) will almost ALWAYS think you are referring to them with those kinds of questions. BUT, in some cases it's fine, so it really depends on your students personalities